# Jquery Slider with Business Catalyst

Tags: jquery, business-catalyst

If you check the Site [Here](http://cleanenergycap.businesscatalyst.com/%5d).

Near the footer you will find "LATEST NEWS" ...

I am using bxslider.. As of now it's only showing 1 title per slide. 
What i want is probably 2 or 3 titles per slide. Possible?

Here is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/jquery.bxslider.css" media="screen" />
<div style="margin-top: -19px;">
    <ul class="bxslider">
        {module_blogpostlist,-1}
    </ul>
</div>
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $('.bxslider .blog-post').each(function(index) {
            $(this).insertBefore('<li>');
            $(this).insertAfter('</li>');
        });
    });
</script> 

<script>
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        mode: 'fade',
        captions: true
    });
</script>
```

Comment: By titles are you referring to the text displaying inside the slide?

Comment: Yes, the blog post title.. i want to show 3 or 2.. at the same time.

Comment: Wouldn't this depend on the data you are getting? Not the slider options. How are you retrieving your data and determining where to put it? I am assuming you have an ajax call somewhere.

Comment: does this code has anything to do with it? {module_blogpostlist,-1}

Comment: That looks like some sort of templating code. If it was jquery it would probably be something like `.ajax()`, `.get()` or `.json()`